# PHP 7 "declaration..should be compatible" for argument types

Tags: php, inheritance, arguments, php-7

I'm using a framework which has method defined something like

```
class Abc {
  public function doThis($what) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Since I'm using PHP 7 and also fan of PHP codesniffer, it tells me to define function argument types, that said I have wrote class in my code:-

```
class Pqr extends Abc {
  public function doThis(string $what) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This code gives me warning Declaration of Pqr::doThis(string $what) should be compatible with Abc::doThis($what)

It seems PHP is treating $what in Abc class differently (not as string). Since Abc is part of framework and I cannot do anything about it. I do not want to remove argument types in my code and want to keep cngode more strict. Disabling all warnings would be bad idea.

Anything better we have to fix this issue ?

Comment: You are overloading that method So the parameters must be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code Sniffer may well be telling you to do something, and you may want to follow its advice, but if your framework isn't doing it then you may not be able to do it either. You can't dicatate the code rules to the framework; you have to live with what it imposes on you, even if that goes against Code Sniffer's rules.

My advice is to simply ignore this issue. Code Sniffer is a great tool, and its advice is worth following, but there are times when you simply can't do so.

If your goal is to get your system to show zero Code Sniffer warnings, then you can do so by explicitly adding markers to your code telling Code Sniffer to ignore specific rules at various points in your code. Code Sniffer has the ability to ignore sections of code; this is described in it's [Advanced Usage](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#ignoring-files-and-folders) documentation page.